# How to use the app.config file in VSTO Outlook 2007 AddIn

Tags: vsto, app-config, outlook-addin

How can we access the app.config file for an Outlook VSTO Addin?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConfigurationManager class in System.Configuration assembly, you should add a reference to this assembly.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134260.aspx)

Comment: This refers to the outlok.exe.config and not the addins config file.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(outlookPath)` you can obtain the path from this key in the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\InstallRoot, where <version> is the number of the outlook version